# 'Pacific/Auckland' time = UTC time

Tags: time, timezone

I've been trying to fix the time on my Ubuntu 16.04 host but can't get the time zone corrected. For some reason Ubuntu thinks Pacific/Auckland time zone is the same as UTC, and do not have a 12 hour offset.
'Pacific/Auckland' time zone is supposed to be UTC +12

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
>
> ```
> Current default time zone: 'Pacific/Auckland'  
> Local time is now:      Tue Sep 26 09:08:37 UTC 2017.  
> Universal Time is now:  Tue Sep 26 09:08:37 UTC 2017.
> ```

timedatectl status

> ```
>       Local time: Tue 2017-09-26 09:13:45 Pacific  
>   Universal time: Tue 2017-09-26 09:13:45 UTC  
>         RTC time: Tue 2017-09-26 09:13:45
>        Time zone: Pacific/Auckland (Pacific, +0000)
>  Network time on: no
> NTP synchronized: no
>  RTC in local TZ: yes
> ```
>
> Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local time zone.
>           This mode can not be fully supported. It will create various problems
>           with time zone changes and daylight saving time adjustments. The RTC
>           time is never updated, it relies on external facilities to maintain it.
>           If at all possible, use RTC in UTC by calling
>           'timedatectl set-local-rtc 0'.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Just did a

> ```
> sudo ntpdate nz.pool.ntp.org
> ```
>
> and got
>       `25 Sep 22:38:17 ntpdate[1422]: step time server 130.217.226.49 offset -43211.035177 sec`
>   and did
>      `date`
>      `Mon Sep 25 22:49:05 Pacific 2017`
>   But the current time is 11:49am.

Comment: Did you perform the step the timedatectl warning suggested?

Comment: yes, didn't fix the problem. It only set "RTC in local TZ: no" and no more warning.

Comment: Is the BIOS configured in UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. My /usr/share/zoneinfo/NZ got corrupted by a rouge unit test. The "NZ" file was originally a binary file and got replaced by a text file with "NZST-12NZDT,M9.5.0,M4.1.0/3"
I copied the NZ file from another machine and that fixed my problem.

timedatectl status

now says:
      Local time: Sat 2017-09-30 02:33:09 NZDT
  Universal time: Fri 2017-09-29 13:33:09 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2017-09-29 13:33:12
       Time zone: Pacific/Auckland (NZDT, +1300)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no